# Opening in dropped ceiling causes room to get warm

Tags: insulation, ceiling

I've moved into a new home last year. One attached room is a workshop with a drop ceiling and it was comfortable at around 70 degrees last summer with the air conditioning. This year, I moved a piece of equipment in there and had to removed a section of the ceiling to accommodate the equipment height as it's about three inches higher. I now have one to two feet of open space around the equipment.

It got into the 80s yesterday and the room got quite warm, about 75F. I assume it was because I removed part of the ceiling which lets the much warmer air above it to filter down to some extent.

I'm trying to find something to put over the space in the ceiling. I can't build anything permanent cause I need access to the top of that on occasion. I'm thinking I could make a light frame of sorts that could lay up there but what would I put in it to keep it easily movable and not too awkward? I can't just throw insulation up there cause I can't worry about fibers from that.

Or is there a better idea? Of course, I don't want this to be expensive either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information or a photo, my answer is to purchase a replacement ceiling tile, cut it to fill your gaps, put the original tile you removed in storage so you will have it if you move out of the space.

Comment: Funny. After taking the dogs for a walk, I thought to myself, "Stupid me. I could just take some tile, cut it to size, and lay it up there."

Comment: Outstanding. Great minds think alike.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have done a lot of work in attics... But one little gap and you can feel the incredibly wrong air currents when there is a conditioned space next to a non-conditioned.  This vortex of air flow can cause dramatic energy costs.

So if you have an unconditioned outdoor space that has a drop ceiling next to a conditioned room the number one thing I would do is add a tremendous layer of insulation between these rooms, starting with the ceiling portion.

I personally would buy ROXUL or fiberglass insulation and install this into the upper ceiling between each joist space.  You can use duct tape to keep them in place and fill gaps but they need to be cut well.

You also need to try to keep the ceiling closed, as the insulation will probably not be able to be perfectly installed unless you got rid of the drop ceiling.  Any kind of cover would work here.  The insulation should provide 80% support but having the ceiling closed will be an important last step to reduce migrant warm airflow.

Comment: You misunderstand my problem. The only space I have an issue with  is the workshop. It has two vents feeding AC into the room. Since removing part of the drop ceiling around this equipment, it appears to have increased the temp in the room by five degrees or more.

Comment: OK will update.

Comment: Still, the only part that applies is your last paragraph. That is what I am asking; what's the best way to close up that space. I am not going to add insulation above the ceiling.

Comment: @Rob - I write answers for the best thing to do because someone else might have the same issue.  If your question only applies to you because you want to half ass it then this is the wrong place to write it.  Anyone in your situation is costing themselves a lot of money by not having the ceiling insulates.  How do you close it up?  Piece of cardbard and velcro if you want cheap.  What you put there doesn't matter as long as it covers the space.